# Release Management 2013 stuck on deployment step

Tags: ms-release-management

I have a Release Management 2013 release that is stuck on a deployment step.  I believe I know what happened, I just don't know how to get it moving forward.

There are multiple release templates that use the Servers with Agents to run PowerShell scripts.  The situation came up that one of the releases, call it release Alpha, seemed to be stuck and I couldn't determine why, so I re-started the Microsoft Deployment Agent.  The reason Alpha was stuck is that the Agent was actively working on a deployment step for a different release template, call it Beta.  When I restarted the Agent, it picked up the first deployment step for Alpha and finished successfully.  However, Beta never finished and is sitting in the `In Progress` status.

I would like to know if there is anyway for me to push the deployment step for Beta into any other status so that the whole process continues.  I am under the gun here for timing, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

**EDIT**
After about 6 hours of waiting the release Beta finally failed.  In the mean time I also attempted to restart the Release Management Monitor service.  This resulted in disabling my Release Management Client app with a "License Expired" message.  That message finally went away after I rebooted the server where the Release Managagement Monitor service was running.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're over the initial problem, but for future (which is likely with the thick RM client) there's a table in the database which contains the current step status. Steps "In progress" will return with the following query (status = 2 is in progress):

```
FROM [ReleaseManagement].[dbo].[ReleaseV2ActivityLog]
where status = '2'
```

If you cannot wait for an unspecified duration for the timeout and also don't want the server restarted for fear of impact, you can change this status column to the value '3' which will mark the step as 'succeeded' and should move you on:

```
update [ReleaseManagement].[dbo].[ReleaseV2ActivityLog]
set Status = '3'
where Status = '2'
```

Obviously amend the query to target the correct "in progress" step by specifying the workflowID or something similarly unique.